# What about initialization many static instance? Have anyone ever seen the usage?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to programming so want to know whether there exists the bad smell in the below code?

```
public class TransportationInfo
{
    public string TableName { get; private set; }
    public string PKName { get; private set; }

    public static TransportationInfo Bicycle = new TransportationInfo() 
    { 
        TableName = "bicycle_table",
        PKName = "aaa"
    };
    public static TransportationInfo Moto = new TransportationInfo()
    {
        TableName = "moto_table",
        PKName = "bbb"
    };
    public static TransportationInfo Car = new TransportationInfo()
    {
        TableName = "car_table",
        PKName = "ccc"
    };
    public static TransportationInfo Bus = new TransportationInfo()
    {
        TableName = "bus_table",
        PKName = "ddd"
    };

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        // use TableName dosomething...
        // use PKName dosomething...
    }
}
```

Then, I can call the function in other class with the code snippet

TransportationInfo.**XXXXX**.DoSomething()

But, is the pattern harmful the overall?

Comment: Definitely not the usual way. Why not use OOP to model Bicycle/Moto/Car/Bus as a type of transportation? Makes it easy to test, extend, clearly signals your intentions etc.

Comment: Is the code in `DoSomething()` going to be the same regardless of the value of `TableName` and `PKName`?

Comment: Yes, I just fetch the raw data with the parameters and then use them to do something else.

Comment: You can't use `TableName` nor `PKName` in the static method `DoSomething()`

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would do that sort of thing with inheritance or interfaces.

```
public abstract class TransportationInfo
{
  public string TableName { get; protected set; }
  public string PKName { get; protected set; }
  public abstract void DoSomething();
}
public class Bicycle : TransportationInfo
{
  public Bicycle()
  { 
    TableName = "bicycle_table";
    PKName = "aaa";
  }
  public override void DoSomething()
  {
        // use TableName dosomething...
        // use PKName dosomething...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `TransportationInfo` class does not contain any methods that need to be virtual, there is no need to consider class inheritance here.

You should probably just use your `TransportationInfo` as a POD (plain old data) class who's sole responsibility is to hold the `TableName` and `PKName` strings:

```
public sealed class TransportationInfo
{
    public string TableName { get; private set; }
    public string PKName    { get; private set; }

    public TransportationInfo(string tableName, string pkName)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
        PKName    = pkName;
    }
}
```

Notice that this is an immutable class - you must assign TableName and PKName in the constructor, and those values cannot thereafter be changed. This is good practice.

Now when you want to create the various instances, you should do so outside the `TransportationInfo` class:

```
var bicycle = new TransportationInfo("bicycle_table", "aaa");
var car     = new TransportationInfo("car_table",     "ccc");
... etc
```

Then you can have another class that is responsible for implementing `DoSomething()`:

```
public sealed class TransportationInfoProcessor
{
    public void DoSomething(TransportationInfo ti)
    {
        // Do something with ti.TableName and ti.PKName.
    }

    ... Other methods, constructor etc.
}
```

Then you can process the instances `car`, `bicycle` etc that you created:

```
var processor = new TransportationInfoProcessor();
processor.DoSomething(bicycle);
processor.DoSomething(car);
... Etc
```

This way you are not violating SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and you have segregated the various areas of concern.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!